# no logs firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

EDIT:
Turns out firebase function filtering is broken on the UI. E.G. If I select the function, no logs show. But I can see logs if I turn off the filter and view all logs

I have a simple firebase function running at host/printLog

Here is my function implementation

```
exports.printLog = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    functions.logger.log("hhellooooo");
    response.send("okie dokie").status(200).end();
})
```

When I send a request to the URL, I get the response "okie dokie", so I know the functions is running, but no log messages.

```
 % curl host/printLog
okie dokie
```

I don't get any logs, even the innovation logs generated by firebase when the function starts and stops. I am still getting logs for some of my other functions, but some of other functions aren't generating logs either

Comment: @zeenathSN it is a bug in firebase, they are working on it

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue that you are receiving with the logs.

I deployed the function that you have provided in your question

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
 
// Max height and width of the thumbnail in pixels.
exports.printLog = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 functions.logger.log("hhellooooo");
 response.send("okie dokie").status(200).end();
})
```

I sent a request to the URL, and in the logs I am receiving the hhellooooo, and even when I filter according to the name of the Function, it’s working fine as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]